# How to get the file shared persons details from OneDrive using graph API

Tags: c#, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to read the permission details and the persons whom the file being shared in OneDrive. 
While checking the permission I get only the Manage Accessed persons details as *"GrantedTo:"* the rest showing like this.

```
{
  "id": "89sd809e-a6fe-47cf-a563-d21fgac9fa3",
  "roles": [
    "read"
  ],
  "link": {
    "scope": "users",
    "type": "view",
    "webUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
},
```

How can I get those persons details ? Why the API returns grantedTo only for the managed access persons ?

The code that I tried :

```
var permissionss = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["itemID"].Permissions
                        .Request(requestOptions)
                        .WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount())
                        .GetAsync();
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve in addition to the people who have been granted access? Off the top of my head, I can think of additional details about the user object, which permissions have been granted, and information about sharing links. The answer will be different for each of these items, so it is difficult to answer your question without the additional details.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT We have to enter email ids while we sharing the file to some persons who may or may not be in our organization. But while checking permission through API we will get only the persons who have been shared the file through the "managed access" option not by using the "Share" option. Then how do I get the others details along with their permission if I  shared the file through  shared link ?

Comment: NB: "managed access " => Direct access .. sorry for the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the explicit permission for a user can be listed with person details.

What is "explicit permission"? You can give this kind of permission like this:

[image]

[image]

After granting access like this, the person details will be shown via `/permissions` endpoint.

If you use other methods to share this file like this:

[image]

It actually just generates a sharing link. There is no specific audience who has been shared with this file. People who have access to this file will be able to access it via this sharing link.

So you can only get a sharing link `"webUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` in the response.

It is by-design of this Graph endpoint.

Comment: Hi @Allen. Thanks for the answer. So there is no way to get the details of the persons and the permission details if we share the file using sharing link ? Then how do the PowerPoint or OneDrive identifies the permission details when a person open the file using the link?

Comment: @CuriousBee Currently Microsoft Graph doesn't expose an endpoint to tell whom a sharing link is working for. We can only create a sharing link with the `scope` "anonymous" or "organization" via Microsoft Graph API. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#scope-types. If we want to specify certain users in the body, we will get an error "Scope must be either 'organization' or 'anonymous'.". So we can't get the specifc users for a sharing link via Microsoft Graph neither.

Comment: The information you want should be done by some undisclosed API.

Comment: Is there any way to find the same details from ShareWithMe files?

Comment: @CuriousBee ShareWithMe doesn't support this scene. It lists the files shared with the signed in user. Not the users which have been shared this file.

Comment: @CuriousBee No problem. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.